# Is there a way to randomize the loop increase in for loop?

Tags: java, loops, processing

I needed a for loop to increase randomly between a given range (1 to 5).
I've tried the following set of codes but it does not seem to work. This code is written for Processing which is based on Java. My intention was to create a canvas with random points of different color from the background to get paper like texture.

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float xRandom = x + random(1, 5);
float yRandom = y + random(1, 5);

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw() {
  background(#e8dacf);
  for(float x; x <= width; xRandom){
    for (float y ; y <= height; yRandom){
      fill(#f0e2d7);
      stroke(#f0e2d7);
      point(x, y);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `for(float x; x <= width; x += xRandom){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to step forward by a random value, then you have to increment the control variables `x` and `y` randomly:

```java
for (float x=0; x <= width; x += random(1, 5)){

    for (float y=0; y <= height; y += random(1, 5)){

        fill(#f0e2d7);
        stroke(#f0e2d7);
        point(x, y);
    }
}
```

Note, with this distribution,  the dots are aligned to columns, because the x coordinates stay the same while the inner loop iterates.
For a completely random distribution, you have to compute the random coordinates in a single loop. e.g:

```java
int noPts = width * height / 9;
for (int  i = 0; i < noPts; ++i ){

   fill(#f0e2d7);
   stroke(#f0e2d7);
   point(random(1, width-1), random(1, height-1));
}
```

Of course some may have to same coordinate, but that shouldn't be noticeable with this amount of points.

Comment: thanks man, once a random is loaded does it stay the same during all the iterations of for loop? I'm getting definite patterns.

Comment: @SamitPaudel No, but your dots are aligned to columns, because the x coordinates stay the same while the inner loop iterates.